# View file with question mark in nginx

Tags: http, nginx, webserver

I've got some code that mirrors some pages using wget, and some of the pages to be mirrored are links like "http://example.com/somepage.php?id=1234". wget ends up saving those pages as "somepage.php?id=1234.html". When I try to visit that page, I get a 404.

I've tried adding "autoindex on;" to the config for that directory to make sure that the filename is correct, and I click on the link generated by nginx when I visit the directory that contains that page, and I still get a 404.

How can I get nginx to serve pages with a question mark in the name?

Comment: Have you tried visiting `somepage.php%3Fid=1234.html`?

Comment: Of course, that worked, thanks. I guess it's a bug in nginx that its directory listing doesn't automatically escape characters

Comment: O.K., so you should post that solution as an answer, and accept it, so this no longer shows up as an unanswered question. (Probably I should have posted my comment as an answer to begin with, but I wasn't sure that it would work!)

Comment: Oh, and -- you're quite welcome. :-)

Comment: "Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking" :(

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll repost my comment as an answer, then.

Comment: My solution was to do a "rewrite" in nginx.conf, then change the filename on disk to not use a question mark :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To future readers: visiting `somepage.php%3Fid=1234.html` worked. (See the comments above.)

Comment: why doesn't nginx automatically accept ? , wouldn't i have to put %3F in my html file instead of ?

Comment: I hate to say this 11 years late, but IMO this is not a real answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue too, the solution was replacing `try_files $uri` with `try_files $request_uri`.

Or you could use both:

```
try_files $uri $request_uri =404;
```